# Watching array stored in Vuex in VueJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuex

I have a customer list which is actually an array of objects. I store it in Vuex. I render the list in my component and each row has a checkbox. More precisely I use keen-ui and the checkbox rendering part looks like:

```
<tr v-for="customer in customers" :class="{ selected: customer.selected }">
    <td>
      <ui-checkbox :value.sync="customer.selected"></ui-checkbox>
    </td>
    <td>{{ customer.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ customer.email }}</td>
</tr>
```

So the checkbox directly changes customers array which is bad: I use strict mode in Vuex and it throws me an error.

I want to track when the array is changed and call an action in order to change the vuex state:

```
watch: {
 'customers': {
  handler() {
    // ...
  },

  deep: true
}
```

However it still changes the customer directly. How can I fix this?

Comment: what about creating a deep copy of the original customer array and use in the template ?

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, be careful when using `.sync`: it will be deprecated in 2.0.

Take a look at this: http://vuex.vuejs.org/en/forms.html, as this problem is solved in here. Basically, this checkbox should trigger a `vuex` action on `input` or `change`. Taken from the docs:

```
<input :value="message" @input="updateMessage">
```

Where `updateMessage` is:

```
vuex: {
  getters: {
    message: state => state.obj.message
  },
  actions: {
    updateMessage: ({ dispatch }, e) => {
      dispatch('UPDATE_MESSAGE', e.target.value)
    }
  }
}
```

If you do not wish to track the mutations, you can move the state of this component away from `vuex`, to be able to use `v-model` in all its glory.

Comment: Meant Vue 3.0 ?

Answer (score 1):

You just have to make a custom getter and setter:

```
<template>
    <ui-checkbox :value.sync="thisCustomer"></ui-checkbox>
</template>

<script>
    //this is using vuex 2.0 syntax
    export default {
        thisCustomer: {
            get() {
                return this.$store.state.customer;
            },
            set(val) {
                this.$store.commit('SET_CUSTOMER', val);
                // instead of performing the mutation here,
                 // you could also use an action:
                  // this.$store.disptach('updateCustomer')
            }
       },
   }
</script>
```

In your store:

```
import {
    SET_CUSTOMER,
} from '../mutation-types';

const state = {
    customer: null,
};

const mutations = {
    [SET_CUSTOMER](state, value) {
        state.customer = value;
    },
}
```

I'm not exactly sure what your store looks like, but hopefully this gives you the idea :)

Comment: This answer fails to properly explain how to use a computed property with a v-for, a statement that the op is showing in his code

Answer (score 1):

if your customers are in the root state, you can try this:

```js
watch: {
 '$store.state.customers'{
   handler() {
    // ...
   },

   deep: true
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try using **mapState** in your component and watch the customers like you have done above.worked for me